# How can a get the camera to move smoothly to a new vector3 position on the click of a button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and I am trying to move the main camera across a background to focus on a new position.

This is what I have so far. It is really basic but I am look for a smooth transition to the new position.

Any help would be great.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Play_Canvas : MonoBehaviour
{
public void OnButtonClick()
{

  Camera.main.transform.position = new Vector3(-11, -5, -10);

}

}
```

Comment: At first glance this looks like you're trying to perform animation via code. Have you considered using Unity's built in animator to do this? Otherwise you can look into using Vector3.Lerp and Time.deltaTime to do this via code.

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do. I had not thought about using the animator. Might give that a shot,

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Vector3.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) within your `Update()` as follows:

```
    Vector3 position = new Vector3 (100, 100, 100);
    void Update () {
        Camera.main.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (Camera.main.transform.position, position, Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

You can also look at Tween packages like [iTween](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/itween-84) to tween the gameobject to a position over x seconds like:

```
Vector3 position = new Vector3 (100, 100, 100);
void Start () {
    iTween.MoveTo (Camera.main.gameObject, position, 3);
}
```